# class design woes

Tags: c++

I'd like to get some advice on designing classes in a situation similar to the example below. B and C objects may or may not have a number component. The problem is that there is no way to selectively call a NumberComponent constructor. Is there a better way to design this?

```
class NumberComponent
{
public:
//Objects which don't have a number component just store a null pointer.
//Any time we do anything here, we have to make sure p_int isn't null.
NumberComponent() : p_int(0) { }
NumberComponent(int x) { p_int = new int(x); }
~NumberComponent() { delete p_int; }

void DoSomething() { if(p_int) ++(*p_int); }

//In real situation, this will be another complex class object.
//Using an int* here to keep this class simple for example.
int* p_int;
};

//B objects may or may not have a number component.
class B : public NumberComponent
{
public:
//If hasNumberComponent is false, we'd like to call the default constructor.
//If hasNumberComponent is true, we'd like to call NumberComponent(int) constructor.
B(int x, bool hasNumberComponent) {}

int value;
};

//C objects may or may not have a number component.
class C : public NumberComponent
{
public:
//If hasNumberComponent is false, we'd like to call the default constructor.
//If hasNumberComponent is true, we'd like to call NumberComponent(int) constructor.
C(int x, bool hasNumberComponent) {}

int value;
};

int main()
{
//myList contains NumberComponent* to B and C objects 
std::list<NumberComponent*> myList;

myList.push_back(new B(5, true));
myList.push_back(new C(3, true));

for(std::list<NumberComponent*>::iterator i = myList.begin(); i != myList.end(); ++i)
    (*i)->DoSomething();

//These objects don't have a Number component.
B b(2, false);
C c(1, false);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `B` and `C` derive from `NumberComponent`, then they **are** `NumberComponent`s.  So it doesn't make sense to say that they "may or may not have a number component".

Comment: Incidentally: don't use dynamically-allocated objects (i.e. via `new`) unless you have to.  I can't see any reason to use `new` in your example code!

Comment: I think that I'm a little confused in how I am thinking about this. I'd like for some B and C objects to have a p_int and be able to do things like DoSomething(). Other B and C objects will be identical except that they don't need a p_int and shouldn't be able to do things like DoSomething().

Comment: Then they aren't the same type of object.  The whole point of a class is that it describes the behaviour for all objects of that class.  If you want different objects to do different things, then they need to be of different classes.

Comment: @user987280: Put identical features in a base class, and inherit from them and add extra features in the derived classes.

Comment: Let's say I leave B and C alone and then create 2 child classes - BWithNumbers which inherits from both B and NumberComponent and CWithNumbers which inherits from both C and NumberComponent. Does that sound about right?

Comment: That's certainly a possibility.  Other factors may or may not make that a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are better designs, you can solve your immediate problem like this:

```
class NumberComponent
{
public:
NumberComponent(int x,bool hasNumberComponent)
  : p_int(hasNumberComponent ? new int(x) : 0) { }
~NumberComponent() { delete p_int; }

void DoSomething() { if(p_int) ++(*p_int); }

//In real situation, this will be another complex class object.
//Using an int* here to keep this class simple for example.
int* p_int;
};

//B objects may or may not have a number component.
class B : public NumberComponent
{
public:
B(int x, bool hasNumberComponent) : NumberComponent(x,hasNumberComponent) {}

int value;
};

//C objects may or may not have a number component.
class C : public NumberComponent
{
public:
C(int x, bool hasNumberComponent) : NumberComponent(x,hasNumberComponent) {}

int value;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of bad design here. Have you considered to use inheritance for what it was invented for:

```
class B
{
   public:
      B(int x):
         m_val(x)
      {
      }

      virtual void doSomething()
      {
          //something
      }

   private: //might be protected as well
       m_val;
};

class BWithNumberComponent : public B
{
   public:
     BWithNumberComponent(int x):
         B(x),
         m_numberComponent(x)
     {
     }

     virtual void doSomething()
     {
       //something else
     }

   private:
     NumberComponent m_numberComponent;
};
```

Comment: This seems like a better way to go design wise, except that I wouldn't be able to have a std::list of objects which use NumberComponent. I want to be able to have a list of both B and C objects which have a NumberComponent capability so that I can call DoSomething() on them.  I think that the only way to do this is to have B and C both inherit from the same parent class.

Comment: @user987280 same parent class, but not necessarily `NumberComponent`, which seems to be some kind of extra feature for your objects. You flattened your structure by degradating extra interface it provided to a property (if it's false nothing happens). Also don't mess responsibilities of your objects. If you need some common method for `B` and `C`, then define pure abstract class `DoSomethingInterface` with abstract virtual method `doSomething()`, inherit this and implement in `B` and `C`.